# WebApi async vs sync

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

I'm new to .Net WebApi, as I know it's preferable to use async APIs instead of sync ones, but what is the difference? 
if the API is sync and has been called from a client, and another call from another client, as I checked, no interruption will happen, and both calls will go through simultaneously. So, what's the benefit of making it Async?

Update: as I understand, if the number of requests are huge, if I use async, the waiting time for some calls will be less, cause there are more threads available to run tasks(as some of them are released waiting for database call, or network call etc.) is it true?

Comment: Async delegates work to operating system and allows threads to process other requests.

Comment: async/sync here is not about being responsive to other clients but about *not blocking server resources* whilst waiting for other things to happen. Frequently, servers are waiting for e.g. databases, other network calls, the file system, etc.

Comment: By using Asynchronous programming, the Application can continue with the other work that does not depend on the completion of the whole task.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [difference between Asynchronous and Synchronous in .net 4.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27742698/difference-between-asynchronous-and-synchronous-in-net-4-5)

Comment: so when the server is waiting for databases etc. other client can be served or it will wait for the db to return the thread?

Comment: If you go async "all the way down" then [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html)

Comment: I know this has to be closed for a duplicate or an off-topic reason, and i cant find any!

Comment: @TheGeneral - I was hesitating over whether to use [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516213/make-webapi-actions-async?rq=1) already in the "Related" section

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I've never seen *why* `async`/`await` is more beneficial than sync calls answered sufficiently (i.e. that question's answer is just 'yes' with no explanation of why)

Comment: @CollinDauphinee - once you grok that the point of `await` is "I can do no useful work until the thing on the right is completed, free this thread to do other things until this happens, rather than selfishly blocking it doing no useful work", I've found I don't need much more motivation for any more *specific* scenarios where I can use it. I just get irked when I'm unable to use the pattern easily and am forced to block.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever The vast majority of .NET framework `async` methods just defer the blocking to another thread. You're freeing up the calling thread and consuming another thread, usually from the same thread pool as the caller. It's hard to explain the tangible benefit of async over sync in practice, because that simple explanation doesn't hold up under scrutiny of the system libraries.

Comment: @CollinDauphinee - see "there is no thread" already linked to above.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I case of SYNC what happens is that for each request a thread is assigned exclusively and this thread is released only upon completion of particular request.
While in case of ASYNC the thread may be reused by other request.

So if your application is I/O Bound then you can see significant improvement in your application by using ASYNC, if your application is CPU Bound then ASYNC will not be that much useful.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I/O_bound

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CPU-bound

Answer (score 0):

First of all re-iterating the difference between sync and async.

{------------- Sync Task1-------------}{-------------- Sync Task 2------------}

{---------------------- async task 1 --------------------}
                        {---------------------- async task 2 --------------------}

I hope you got your answer by this point to why its beneficial. Imaging a situaion where your API serving list of 1000 basketball payers and their details while requests comings in for list of cities. I bet your client app would look neater if you get something while player list is been served wouldn't it?

Secondly, APIs don't prefer Aync as such. Its a choice of programming you have. If you utilise the full language and operating system capabilities, It's your application and the users going to get the benefit out of it.

CACHING,

Using Async does help caching if you are use new In memory Cache or custom server-level cache. Afterall your client is looking for 304 return and while a long request is been served a small requests can  be served ie cache checks.

Comment: All this is all factually correct, i think this misses the point of the question a little, which is the async await pattern for web services